# ValueError: too many values to unpack strip

Tags: python, list, strip

I am having some data as the following in my file.

```
phone=408-456-7890&param1=2&param2=12&param3=0
phone=510-543-7891&param1=1&param2=12&param3=1
phone=650-857-7892&param1=4&param2=12&param3=2
```

This is my code:

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as fh: 
   data = fh.read()

for i in data.split('&'):
    l = i.strip()
    if l:
        k,v = l.split('=')
        print k,v
```

> ValueError: too many values to unpack

I did a print of each line.

I am getting line breaks. I am not sure what's going on.

```
['phone', '408-456-7890']
['param1', '2']
['param2', '12']
['param3', '0\nphone', '510-543-7891']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try stripping new lines when reading line by line:

```
>>> with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as fh:
...     for l in fh.readlines():
...         for pair in l.strip().split("&"):
...             k, v = pair.split("=")
...             print k, v

'phone', '408-456-7890'
'param1', '2'
'param2', '12'
'param3', '0'
```

Comment: @Paddy why do you think you can't split? At each line `l` will look like this: `phone=408-456-7890&param1=2&param2=12&param3=0`

Comment: Thanks and it makes sense.